# Why doesn't my Gmail user/password work when deploying ASP.NET to Compute Engine inside Visual Studio?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-visualstudio

I created a Compute Engine VM using the ASP.NET Cloud Launcher, and now I want to deploy to it from Visual Studio.

I've created a publish settings file using the Visual Studio extension then tried to deploy using the regular Visual Studio "Publish" command. The settings didn't contain a user name and password, so I used my Gmail/Google credentials - this is a Compute Engine instance that my account has access to, after all:

[image: Publish dialog]

This failed with the following error:

> Web deployment task failed. (Connected to the remote computer
>   ("(redacted)") using the Web Management Service, but could not
>   authorize. Make sure that you are using the correct user name and
>   password, that the site you are connecting to exists, and that the
>   credentials represent a user who has permissions to access the site.
>   Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED.)

If that's not the user name and password to use, what is?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The Compute Engine instance doesn't know about your Google user at all - it only knows about regular Windows accounts, and you don't have a Windows account on it. So, you need to create a Windows account on the instance, and then put that into the publish settings.

In the Google Cloud Explorer, select the instance and choose "Create or Reset Password":

[image: Create or reset account]

You can then choose whatever username you like - I'd suggest "aspnet" for simplicity, for example. Note that this username is a normal Windows account on the machine - it's not specific to your Google user. If you're sharing this machine with others for development, you should agree on a set of account names, either securely sharing credentials for a single account, or creating a separate account per developer. You don't want to reset the password for an account a colleague is using!

This account can also be used to open a Terminal Server session with the Compute Engine instance.

Wait until the user has been created with a password, then copy the password:

[image: Copy password]

You can now put that into your Publish Settings and let Visual Studio save the password - and keep a copy in a separate secure location, should you wish, of course.

Comment: @JeffC: Yes, had forgotten to do so. Done now!